# Regex matching key value pairs inside curly brackets

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I’m trying to capture key:value pairs inside curly brackets. For the following string it should return something like k2:v2 and k3:v3

`Str = “k1:v1abc{k2:v2,k3:v3}{test}”`

I have the following regexes which capture what I need individually, but I don’t know how to combine them together.

`/(\w+):(\w+)/g`  >>> Captures key:value
`/{.*?}/g`  >>> Captures everything between {}

Answer (score 0):

If your environment [supports](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) a quantifier in a lookbehind assertion:

```
(?<={[\w:,]*)\w+:\w+(?=[\w:,]*})
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<={[\w:,]*)` Positive lookbehind, assert `{` and optional repetitions of the allowed chars to the left
- `\w+:\w+` Match 1+ word chars `:` and 1+ word chars
- `(?=[\w:,]*})` Positive lookahead, assert optional repetitions of the allowed chars to the right and `}`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Eiloft/1).

```js
const str = "k1:v1abc{k2:v2,k3:v3}{test}";
const regex = /(?<={[\w:,]*)\w+:\w+(?=[\w:,]*})/g;
console.log(str.match(regex));
```

Another way could be using 2 passes, first matching the format and get the part between the curly braces in a capture group.

If there is a match, split group 1 on a comma.

```
{(\w+:\w+(?:,\w+:\w+)*)}
```

The pattern matches:

- `{` Match opening `{`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\w+:\w+` Match 1+ word chars `:` and 1+ word chars
  - `(?:,\w+:\w+)*` Optionally repeat a `,` and the same previous pattern
- `)`
- `}` Match closing `}`

```js
const str = "k1:v1abc{k2:v2,k3:v3}{test}";
const regex = /{(\w+:\w+(?:,\w+:\w+)*)}/;
const m = str.match(regex);
if (m) console.log(m[1].split(","));
```

Comment: there could be multiple sets of brackets

Comment: @mplungjan Ah in that case the OP should use a recursive pattern that is not supported in js or use a parser. Thanks for the heads up.